# Create a raster which has a value of 1 for where a class of object is present and a value of 0 when it is not in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-calculator, vector-grid, biology

I have probably explained this very badly, but basically I have polygons which outline the extent of individual fish farms in a lake. I have created a 1km by 1km fishnet of the area within said lake, to match the resolution of other environmental variables I want to use for a species distribution model. I want to know how to create a raster so that it has pixels of 1km by 1km, and so that if a polygon of the fish farms is found within the extent of the fishnet pixel, it has a value of 1, and if no fish farm polygon is found, it has a value of 0. I am using ArcGIS for this, ArcMap in particular.

Question Edit:

I have tried to rasterise the polygons of the fish farms, but for some reason that does not seem to produce a raster, or at least it does not produce anything visible in ArcGIS. Neither do the other supposed "duplicate" question answers appear to resolve the issue. I am trying to see if I can have something like zonal calculator for the fishnet, but rather than getting attributes of an underlying raster, tell me which cells of the fishnet have within them polygons of the fish farms, and which do not, and then have a raster which tells me which 1km x 1km squares have fish farms and which do not. I think the misunderstanding about why this question is thought to be answered by the other "duplicate" question is the assumption that there is an overall polygon map of the lake, including the fish farms. That is not the case, there are individual polygons around individual fish farms, and in some cases individual fish cages.

Comment: A web search on "ArcGIS polygon to raster" can't help but show [Polygon to Raster](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/polygon-to-raster.htm) When you try it, if you have the correct licesing, you will note that you need to control for the origin, and that pixels will be set if the center is within, not just crossing the pixel. Depending on the area, Create Fishnet might work better first, with spatial selection, then conversion. As it stands, you probably haven't done enough research to start asking a sufficiently focused Question.

Comment: Look I get that Stack Exchange does not like unfocused questions, but how am I meant to know how to ask a specific enough question if I do not even know what the proper terminology to use is in this instance? I tried to rasterise the polygons, that was the first thing I tried, and when I do that, it just produces, well, I do not know what. IEven when it is the only thing I set to be visible, there is nothing there. I am trying to see if there is something akin to zonal calculator, but to see the intersection between the fishnet and the polygons.

Comment: Fixing your issue with Polygon to Raster would need you to report that issue, with details on your exact parameters. Reporting the license(s) available will help assure that suggestions are possible. It seems obvious that you *need* a polygon map of the lake's fish farms and boundary; if you don't have those then you need to either compile them or do piecemeal masking, which will be much harder. Note that a "fishnet" is a vector data structure, composed of polygon cells. A fishnet would be easily converted to raster, but it might be easier to model this situation as a vector.

Comment: What I have is a bunch of polygons with the outline of the individual fish farms. I also have a polygon of the lake outline. I just need to know how to make a raster that says which 1km by 1km pixels have fish farms in them and which do not

Comment: I already indicated how to do that: Generate Fishnet, use Select by Location with each polygon, then use Polygon to Raster. If you have difficulty with any of those steps, document the problem, and ask about that.